# customize the x-axis of wpf line chart on the basis of filter mvvm c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, charts

I want to change the x-axis of the wpf toolkit line series chart depending upon the filter criteria. Filter contains the 3 checkboxes like 1)Show Today 2) Show Week 3) Show Month. When click on Show Today, It shows the today's records from the database and x-axis should be like 9 am 11 am 1 pm 3pm 5pm 7pm 9pm 11 pm 1am 3 am 5 am 7 am. When Click on Show Week, it should show current week's dates from sunday to saturday. When click on Show Month, it should show from 1 to 31 on x-axis. I am binding the DateTime property to the IndependentValuePath on x-axis. and I am calling the method in my dataaccess on filter change. How to achieve this in wpf line series chart using mvvm.

Kindly suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create a datatrigger for each of the checkboxes in the style of your x-axis.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                        <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis x:Name="LevelsDateTimeAxis" Orientation="X" Minimum="{Binding ElementName=PatientWindow, Path=MinimumTime}" Maximum="{Binding ElementName=PatientWindow, Path=MaximumTime}">
                            <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=WeekCheckbox, Path=IsChecked}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="IntervalType"
                                                    Value="Days" />
                                            <!-- You might need to adjust the Interval to 1 Here -->
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <!-- Continue With the Next Checkbox -->
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis.Style>
                        </chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis>
```